# Age of River Vaigai

Tags: shiva, manu, matsya-purana

During Meenakshi Thirukalyanam, Ganga is supposed to have flown out Lord Sundareshwarar's locks (Lord Shiva) to quench Gundotharan's thirst. And this stream came to be known as Vaigai. Meenakshi Thirukalyanam episode is dated 3138 BCE as per the article at https://www.booksfact.com/history/meenakshi-thirukalyanam-madurai-20-february-3138-bce.html. This means Vaigai is about 5000years old

But there is the story of Matsya Avatara where King Satyavrata, in the Chakshusha manvantara, used to meditate on the banks of river Kritamala. It is said that this Kritamala river is now known as Vaigai.

This is really confusing. Can someone clarify please

Answer (score 1):

That the river is only about 5000 years old is bogus. It is foolish to believe that Meenakshi Kalyanam happened only then. The Matsya Purana legend is reliable. So the river is old by a few million years. Sage Agastya visited Podhigai hills to balance the earth and hence he is known as Siva-Tulya. He witnessed Parvati's marriage from South India. Agastya also brought Kaveri river. I strongly believe both rivers are as ancient as Tamil. Dravideswara or Satyavrat is the name of the progenitor named Vaiswatha Manu. It's there in the Matsya Purana. A Manu lives for more than 30 crore years. We have completed half of the duration.

Comment: You must cite some sources.

Comment: That the river Vaigai is as old as the beginning of the present Vaivasvata manvantara is clear from the Matsya Purana. Kritamala is the Sanskrit name mentioned in the puranas for Vaigai river. The King Satyavrat is on its banks doing ablutions when a small carp appears in his palm and starts speaking to him. This story confirms the age of Vaigai. Matsya Purana maybe downloaded from the internet.